# Does it need to run assets:precompile on worker/ActionMailer only servers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

I use `capistrano-rails` to deploy my Rails application to production servers. In addition to the common `app`, `web`, `db` roles, I define `worker` role for my sidekiq worker servers. These worker servers also handle `ActionMailer` jobs and in the mailer views, I have `asset_url` and `image_url` for `src` attributes of `<img>` tags. Does this mean that I need to run **assets:precompile** on the worker servers by adding the `worker` role to the `assets_roles` configuration? Or do I misunderstand the definition of these different roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: Probably

Long answer: When you precompile assets, two primary things happen. The first is that the images, CSS, JS, fonts, et cetera are processed and written to the public directory with a fingerprint as part of the URL. The second thing is that a manifest file with the mapping from the original asset names to the fingerprinted filenames is created (if you want to look at this file, run `bin/rake assets:precompile` and then look at `public/assets/.sprockets-manifest-*.json`).

When you use the `asset_url` or `image_url` methods, one of the first things they do is look at the generated manifest to get the real filename of the asset in question.

So, while the worker doesn't serve or look at the assets, it would look at the manifest, which is itself generated by creating all of the assets. Therefore, you do need to precompile the assets in order to know the filenames of the assets on your main webservers, and properly populate the links.